# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. > A prob lem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-ndk

I've tried everything to solve this but I still can't. This is the build.gradle: app part that may be causing the problem:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec,description: 'run ndk-build') {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        workingDir 'jni'
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-j' , Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    } else {
        workingDir 'jni'
        commandLine "ndk-build", '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(ndkBuild)
}
```

I also changed this:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9 ( was 4.8)
```

And of course :

```
ndk.dir=C:\Users\Elyes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C:\Users\Elyes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Im using the following command on windows pc

```
task buildNative(type: Exec) {
  workingDir 'jni'// directory app/jni
  commandLine("${android.ndkDirectory}\\ndk-build.cmd", '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors())
}
```